# Displaying div on click submit button

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a radio button and a submit button. On click of this submit button, I need to display a div.

My code is as follows:

```
<form action="" method="GET" name="myform">
    <input type="radio" name="ID" value="total" id="radioInputValue"/>
    <input type="submit" name="details1" value="Details"
           onclick="return showDiv();"/>

    <div id="element_to_pop_up" style="display: none;">
        <?php
        echo "DETAILS";
        if (isset($_GET['details1'])) {
            if (isset($_GET['ID'])) {
                $n = $_GET['ID'];
                echo "VALUE IS = $n";
            }
        } else {
            echo "</br> DETAILS FAILED";
        }?>
    </div>
</form>
```

My JavaScript:

```
function showDiv() {
    document.getElementById('element_to_pop_up').style.display = 'block';
    return false;
}
```

Style:

```
#element_to_pop_up
{ 
   background-color:#fff;
   border-radius:15px;
   color:#000;
   padding:20px;
   min-width:400px;
   min-height: 180px;
}
```

I am getting the div on click of the details button. But its not  entering  the if condition .

Instead its giving the output as:

DETAILS

DETAILS FAILED

I want this as my output:

DETAILS

VALUE IS = total

How can i get this radio button value on clicking submit button, Plz help

Comment: are you sure that you have a querystring with name `ID`?

Comment: yes. coz wen i run my code without onclick function and div it runs fine

Comment: that is because you have a submit button which fires the default function, ie the form action..so try changing that submit button to normal button.

Comment: learn between client side and server side.

Comment: I changed it to button, but still it gives the same output. The value of radio button msg is not getting displayed

Comment: could you please post a fiddle.

Comment: @lal   can u plz go through my code mentioned above ..its the same usage in the fiddle too

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just copy paste it: it works fine..

```
<form action="" method="POST" name="myform">
ONE<input type="radio" name="ID" value="total" id="radioInputValue" />
<input type="submit" name="details1" value="Details" onclick="return showDiv();" />
</form>
<div id="element_to_pop_up">                        
<?php 
echo"DETAILS";
if(isset($_POST['details1']))
{
if(isset($_POST['ID']))
{$n=$_POST['ID'];
echo "VALUE IS = ".$n;
}
else
{
echo"</br> DETAILS FAILED";
}
}
?>
</div>



<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
function showDiv() {
            document.getElementById('element_to_pop_up').style.display = 'block';
           // return false;
        }
        </script>
```

Comment: How can I hide the pop up before handed, on including display:none it fails to work :(

Comment: did you try any pop up plugins??

Comment: I dont want to use plugins. Can we do it without plugins?

Comment: see this http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/

Comment: I used that modal  but I cant get the radio button value inside the <div>

Answer (score -1):

Change your submit button like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="details1" value="Details" onclick="showDiv()" />
```

When you click your button, it displays the div.

Your PHP code should work, but make sure the file is .php and not .html or .htm.